# Expected Value of number of tosses

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

Actually i was solving this question

[Expected value of rolling dice until getting a $3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698177/expected-value-of-rolling-dice-until-getting-a-3)

Formally doing we get $$E(X)=6$$

Does it mean, number of tosses required is $6$?

Answer (score 3):

No. You could of course get $3$ with the first throw with probability $\frac{1}{6}$. The result means that on average you get the first three in $6$ rolls.

Comment: ok so it means if we perform the experiment of tossing a dice $n$ number of times. Now lets say in first experiment we got $3$ in 5th toss. So number of tosses is $5$. Lets say in second experiment we got $3$ in $10$th toss and so on we conducted experiment $1000$ times. In all these $1000$ experiments we recorded number of tosses. Now if take average of all those we get $6$. Is this right?

Comment: @Umeshshankar Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of tosses is equal to 6. Since $X\sim Geo(p)$ $$E(X)=\frac1 p$$ where your $p = 1/6$. It shows you that you will most likely  get a $3$ in $6$ rolls.